# Common practice in C# inheritance on single fields becoming arrays in children

Tags: c#

Say I have a base class `Snake` with an `int health = 10`.

Say I have a derived class `Hydra`. It has different health values for every head.

Would it be good practice to define a new `int[] healths` (one health for every head) in the derived class?
Or should I define the base class with a `int[] healths` collection with only one member?

Comment: Show what you've tried and specifically where you're having an issue.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer: I think the question is clear as it stands.

Comment: @JonathanWood sure, but adding a code sample shows an attempt at resolving it (an SO requirement) and assists other users in answering it. It would also avoid the SO potential flag for closure being 'unclear' or 'off topic'.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer: In this case, there is nothing to solve. He's asking a design question. If he was wondering why his code wouldn't compile or why it produced an unexpected result, then I think your point would be more valid.

Comment: I'm sorry if I am not complying to SO standards. This is my first time on here. I didn't know where else to ask a design question like this. If you have a suggestion where better to ask such a 'good practice' or 'architectural' question I'd be grateful!

Comment: Whiteboard question are typical asked on [SE.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), but they have high standards. I think it is okay to ask this on SO. What most people miss, is that an [mcve] is required for debugging questions. Here is nothing to debug...

Comment: Thanks. I will check SE.SE too.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt The standards are the same on SO. But the high volume of questions made it impossible to flag them all.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a different logic per Monster, than each monster should have a different Implementation. Therefore I would create an Interface:

```
public interface IMonster
{
    public int Health {get;}
}
```

And then two different concrete Implementations:

```
public Snake : IMonster
{
    public int Health {get; set;}
}

public Hydra : IMonster
{
    public int HeadHealth {get; set;}
    public int BodyHealth {get; set;}
    public int Health => HeadHealth + BodyHealth;
}
```

Then you can access the Health via the Interface:

```
void DisplayHealth(IMonster monster)
{
    Console.WriteLine(monster.Health);
}    

var hydra = new Hydra
{
    HeadHealth = 25,
    BodyHealth = 100
}

var snake = new Snake
{
    Health = 50
}

DisplayHealth(hydra) //125
DisplayHealth(snake) //50
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I would never have come up with this. I will try it. Both your and Jonathan Woods idea agree on using a general Health Property in both Snake and Hydra that do different things. That's the base idea I will take with me. I believe it will suit my needs.

Answer (score 1):

I would just create `int[] Healths` in the derived class. There's no reason to put this in the base class if the base class doesn't use it.

One thought though is that, if your `Health` property is virtual, the `Hydra` class should still implement it. Maybe the implementation should traverse the `Healths` property and return a single value that reflects the overall health. But that sort of depends on your needs.

```
class Snake
{
    public virtual int Health { get; }
}

class Hydra : Snake
{
    public int[] Healths { get; }

    public override int Health
    {
        get
        {
            // Or whatever is meaningful
            return (int)Healths.Average();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is a nice way of doing it. I will try it out.